# Selecting blockquote after specific span with Xpath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xpath

So, at the moment I'm using Xpath to retrieve the text from blockquote tags, but I need to be able to select SPECIFIC blockquotes.
The only difference between the two types I need is that they are directly after spans.
Let's say I need to get text1 and text2 from each other, this would be the HTML:

```
<span id="1">some code here</span>
<blockquote>text1</blockquote>

more code in here

<span id="2">some code here</span>
<blockquote>text</blockquote>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: By the way, I'm using "//blockquote/node()" to get the text currently.

Comment: +1 for good question. Next time make sure to add all necessary details.

Comment: I will stay till -1. After that I'll delete my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
//span[starts-with(@id,'nothread')]/following::*[1][name()='blockquote']
```

This will get all the wanted blockquote elements.

To get the text nodes:

```
//span[starts-with(@id,'nothread')]/following::*[1][name()='blockquote']/text()
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well, and is a bit more readable than the other answer. Can I set them both as the correct answer?..

Comment: Don't think @polishchuk will care about. He's gone with 3 upvotes and really his XPath turned a bit complicated.

Comment: @polishchuk I know it's very irritating :) it happened to me sometime, much worst without any meaningful explanation :((

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have this XML:

```
<root>
<span id="1 nothread">some code here</span>
<blockquote>text1</blockquote>

more code in here

<span id="2 nothread">some code here</span>
<blockquote>text</blockquote>

<span id="3">some code here</span>
<blockquote>text</blockquote>

<blockquote>not selected text</blockquote>
</root>
```

So, this XPath: `//blockquote[local-name(preceding::*[1]) = 'span' and contains(preceding::*[1]/@id, 'nothread')]/node()` selects all `blockquote` if it is directly after span and span/@id contains `nothread`.
Result:

1. text1
2. text

So you see, `not selected text` wasn't selected

Comment: Thanks, but I need to get text1 and text seperately. By span id. I need to check if the span id contains "nothread" (forgot to mention this part in my post, sorry), and if it does, get the text from the blockquote after it. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: @polishchuck: Unfortunately this isn't working and I have no idea why. Even just using "//blockquote[local-name(preceding::*[1]) = 'span']/node()" won't work for some reason.

Comment: Ignore my last post, using preceding::*[5] worked instead. I forgot to mention the span had tags inside of it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok guys, I know it was not a nice suggestion!! @polishchuk it turned good for you anyway, even better :D